# Steam on DigitalOcean droplet with GUI as game machine

Tags: games, steam, vnc

I installed xfce and Steam on a Digital Ocean droplet with the intention of being able to run strategy games from the droplet through.

I've gotten the two above pieces of software installed, but when I try to run Steam it throws the following error "OpenGL GLX extension not supported by display".

I expect that it's something to do with graphics drivers, as droplets weren't designed to be running graphics intensive software, but can't seem to find a conclusive solution.

Here is my process so far:

1. Install 16.04 (64bit) and get it working with VNC by following this guide: 
   https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-14-04
2. Install steam by doing the following:
   64-bit Ubuntu

   - add the following line to `/etc/apt/sources.list`
   - `deb http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ precise steam`
   - `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install steam-launcher`
3. Double click steam icon and get the above error
   `"OpenGL GLX extension not supported by display"`

This is the output from `sudo lshw -c video`:

```
description: VGA compatible controller
       product: QXL paravirtual graphic card
       vendor: Red Hat, Inc.
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 04
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f8000000-fbffffff memory:fc000000-fcffffff memory:fd090000-fd091fff ioport:c0a0(size=32) memory:fd080000-fd08ffff
```